# Route::redirect();

Tags: laravel

Как сделать редирект на именнованный роут

`Route::redirect('/foo', '/bar', 301);` так работает

хочу что-то типа 
`Route::redirect('/foo', route('bar'), 301);` в идеале без калбэка

Answer (score 0):

```
    Route::get('/foo', function(){
        return redirect(route('bar'), 301);
        // Или
        // return redirect()->route('bar', 301);
    });
```

К сожалению с коллбеками не работает кеширование роутов, поэтому желательно создать контроллер, например `RedirectsController` и перенести в него коллбеки.

Хотя по идее, роуты еще не загружены и без калбэка никак((((